How to display image from Strapi collection content
Im having trouble receiving the media attribute of my content in my collection from strapi on my 11ty project. Every time I try something with trying to recieve my image data it breaks my page.
Strapi collection
Below is a the portion of my eleventy.config.js file that is working on this collection:
// Cardio Exercises Collection
 eleventyConfig.addCollection("cardioExercises", async function() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/exercises?filters[workout][Slug][$eq]=cardio", { timeout: 5000 });
    console.log("Fetched Cardio Exercises Data (Response):", response.data);

    if (!response.data.data || response.data.data.length === 0) {
      console.error("Cardio exercises data missing or empty:", response.data);
      return [];
    }

    const imageUrl = attributes?.Image?.data?.attributes?.url
  ? `http://localhost:1337${attributes.Image.data.attributes.url}`
  : null;
    return response.data.data.map((exercise) => {
      return {
        id: exercise.id,
        name: exercise.Name,
        exerciseSlug: exercise.Slug,
        description: exercise.Description?.[0]?.children?.[0]?.text || "No description available",
        image: imageUrl,
      };
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch strength training exercises from Strapi:", error);
    return [];
  }
});

and here is my page that displays the content of the collection :
---
layout: layout.hbs
pagination:
  data: collections.cardioExercises
  size: 1
  alias: exercise
permalink: "/workouts/cardio/exercises/{{ exercise.exerciseSlug }}/index.html"
---
<section class="exercise-detail-section">
  <div class="container exercise-container">
    
    <!-- Image Section -->
    <div class="exercise-image">
      <!-- Dynamically rendering images based on the exercise image field from Strapi -->
      {{#if exercise.image }}
        <img src="{{ exercise.image }}" alt="{{ exercise.name }} Exercise Image">
      {{else}}
        <img src="/css/default-exercise.png" alt="Default Exercise Image">
      {{/if}}
    </div>

    <!-- Text Section: Exercise Name and Description -->
    <div class="exercise-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>{{ exercise.name }}</h1> <!-- Exercise name -->
        <p>{{ exercise.description }}</p> <!-- Exercise description -->
      </div>

      <!-- Back Button to navigate back to the Cardio page -->
      <div class="back-button">
        <a href="/" class="button">
          Back to Home  <!-- Button text -->
          <span class="span"></span> <!-- Span for hover effect -->
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>


Not sure if I'm doing this correctly...
Help will be appreciated!

The issue is that attributes is not defined globally, and you’re trying to fetch the image URL outside the .map() loop, where the exercise object is available.
You might need to move the image URL fetching logic inside the .map() function, as the attributes might exist in the exercise object and will only be accessible within the loop. Something like the code below depending on how the exercise object is structured.
return response.data.data.map((exercise) => {
  const imageUrl = exercise?.attributes?.Image?.data?.attributes?.url
    ? `http://localhost:1337${exercise.attributes.Image.data.attributes.url}`
    : null;

  return {
    id: exercise.id,
    name: exercise.Name,
    exerciseSlug: exercise.Slug,
    description: exercise.Description?.[0]?.children?.[0]?.text || "No description available",
    image: imageUrl,
  };
});

